# Retornar valores asi este vacio MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos Estoy haciendo una consulta en MYSQL pero si esta vacio el where in no me retorna valores.

```
SELECT objects.*, GROUP_CONCAT(mvalues.value SEPARATOR ", ") as value, 
GROUP_CONCAT(mdescriptor.name SEPARATOR ", ") as name FROM objects JOIN 
metadata_values mvalues ON mvalues.idObject = objects.idObject JOIN 
metadata_descriptors mdescriptor ON mvalues.idDescriptor = 
mdescriptor.idDescriptor WHERE objectType = 'EMBED' AND mdescriptor.name 
IN ('Year Created', 'Thumbnail Patch', 'Latlng') AND objects.idObject IN 
(SELECT idObject FROM metadata_values WHERE value IN ('Adornment')) GROUP 
BY objects.idObject LIMIT 0, 5
```

Si esta parte de codigo sql esta vacio no me retorna valores

```
objects.idObject IN (SELECT idObject FROM metadata_values WHERE value IN ('Adornment'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te va a retornar nada si dejas el where in vacio, no se donde estas armando la condicion, pero deberias condicionar el query a que si no hay filtros no utilice la condicion, o simplemente separar en varios where el "in" y pasar 1=1 si es que no se necesitan filtros.

Comment: Saludos para que sea mejor recibida tu respuesta pon un  [mcve]